# How to set up RPX widget and facebook app to be able to authenticate with rpx_now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, facebook, rpxnow, rpx

Using the sample app for `rpx_now` gem ( http://github.com/grosser/rpx_now_example) on localhost:3000, I have successfully logged in via Google Accounts, myOpenID, Yahoo, but cannot make it via Facebook.

In the RPX app/widget settings I have set my facebook-app key and secret. In my facebook app settings, the Connect URL is `myappname.rpxnow.com`. But when I try to connect, then I don't even see a facebook login page, just a number of redirects and I am back to my localhost with the following exception http://gist.github.com/386520 .

Before I was successfully connecting with `oauth2` gem, however, without fetching user data - only authentication. That time I set only key/secret and `localhost` as my Connect URL. Currently, I don't even ask for email etc., but still the same problem.

Can it happen because `rpx_now` cannot get requested user data from facebook? Or it is a problem of facebook key/secret? May be I need to provide more settings of my facebook app?

```
RPXNow::ApiError in UsersController#create

Got error: Invalid parameter: token (code: 1), HTTP status: 200
RAILS_ROOT: /home/Andrei/rpx_now_example

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rpx_now-0.6.20/lib/rpx_now/api.rb:71:in `parse_response'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rpx_now-0.6.20/lib/rpx_now/api.rb:21:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rpx_now-0.6.20/lib/rpx_now.rb:23:in `user_data'
/home/Andrei/rpx_now_example/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Response

Headers:

{"Content-Type"=>"",
 "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve it, one needs to go to Facebook application, click "Edit Settings", select "Migrations" on the left column and toggle "New Data Permissions" to disabled. There is a comment next to this parameter: *Enable the new data permissions and the new permissions dialog. (Migration ends on: June 1, 2010)*

So, I guess one needs to update `rpx_now` gem to work with the new interface.